# File downloading in .aspx extension with webForm name

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my **webform (ViewRequest.aspx)** , I've placed a `gridview` where user can download files from the grid .

Files are populating in grid fine with delete and **download** button.but when user downloads file from **google chrome** , **file name is always ViewRequest.aspx** which is the page name . Then user has to go through open with mechanism to open the selected file with suitable format for example PDF reader for pdf files etc.

This problem is not occuring in Internet Explorer . The file name is the same as the name of file in Grid and extension is also alright.

I don't know what could be the problem .

Can any one help me please.

Here is my code to download file

```
protected void Grid_Attachments_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "download")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string url = Grid_Attachments.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(url);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my aspx Page code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid_Attachments" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" OnRowDataBound="Grid_Attachments_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Grid_Attachments_RowDeleting" OnRowCommand="Grid_Attachments_RowCommand">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Files Added">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LBL_Attachment" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FILE_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="UserTableRow" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Added By" DataField="empname">
                                    <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="25%" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="UserTableRow" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Attachment Date" DataField="ATTACHMENT_DATE">
                                    <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="20%" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="UserTableRow" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File Path" DataField="ATTACHMENT_PATH">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:ButtonField ControlStyle-BackColor="#C6304A" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White" ButtonType="Button"
                                    CommandName="download" HeaderText="Download File(s)" ShowHeader="True" Text="Download">
                                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="#CC0000" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                    <ControlStyle BackColor="#C6304A" ForeColor="White"></ControlStyle>
                                    <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="15%" />
                                </asp:ButtonField>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" HeaderText="Action">
                                    <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" />
                                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="#CC0000" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                </asp:CommandField>
                                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmpCode" DataField="emp_code">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hiddencol" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#C6304A" ForeColor="White" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

This is Grid Binding Code :

```
  private void BindAttachmentGrid(string RequestNo)
    {        
        Grid_Attachments.DataSource = attachments.getAllAttachmentForARequest(RequestNo);
        Grid_Attachments.DataBind();
    }
```

**Update :**

I've tried this code but it's only working for pdf files

```
Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                string filetype = file.Extension;
                Response.ContentType = "application/"+filetype;
                Response.Flush();
                Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
                Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to visit this links:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103618
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

try with this code::

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = your content type
Response.Flush();
Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Nothing is happning , Postback occuring

Comment: can you please paste your design page code as well? have you used updatepanel ?

Comment: i've added the code , I didn't use update panel any where on this page

Comment: visit the links provided in my answer: also make sure for different file types you are using the correct content-type

Comment: I can not try different file types because i don't know which type of file will the user upload  . it depends upon the requestor .I'm using Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

Comment: ok, just try with pdf only and see if abovr code works with the content-type: application/pdf ?

Comment: yes , this is fine now , i've tried it with pdf ,now what should i do to handle any other file type

Comment: Now , I've tried it with png  , nothing is happening , only a postback occuring

Comment: that's it. Google chrome requires proper content-type to get the file downloaded. that's what mentioned in the shared link. I will suggest you to read the file type while binding the grid from the URL and based on the file type provide the correct content-type. (before user clicks on download button)..

Comment: What content-type you have selected for PNG ? is it proper ? check the links